# Posts from category not displaying when searching for category name

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble with my search results page in that it is not displaying posts that are a part of a category when searching for the category name.  For Instance, If I search for "doors" (which is a cat) all Partners that are in the "doors" category should be displayed in the search results.  Right now, only partners that have the word "doors" in their title or content is displayed.

I'm running a searchAll function so the the standard wp search will search everything.

```
// Define what post types to search
function searchAll( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'partner','project', 'press', 'review' ));
}
return $query;
}
// The hook needed to search ALL content
add_filter( 'the_search_query', 'searchAll' );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

your query is seraching for `post_type`, not `category_name`.

post_type is used for custom post types or taxonomies ..

your query should contain `$query->set( 'category_name', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'partner','project', 'press', 'review' ));`

however, in some cases (and I do not know the reason) that would not work for sub-categories.
in that case, you should use category-slug (slug) insted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, getting a parse error from formatting.php

Comment: well, this query should work, a parse error is more likely a syntax problem somewhere in your code . can you post the error code ?

Comment: Ive changed my string to this:

    '// Define what post types to search
    function searchAll( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'category_name', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'partner','project',
    'press', 'review' ));
    }
    return $query;
    }
    // The hook needed to search ALL content
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchAll' );'

I do have custom taxonomies though.  Basically I'm trying to create a "Search everything" function.  The site is www.remodelcard.com

Comment: Okay, Im getting confused now. I've changed my string to what you suggested, but get a parse error when searching. The custom taxonomies are; "feed,partner,press,review"  Within $query->set should I have both post_type and category_name since I want everything to be searchable?

Comment: Can you please post the whole error code , and maybe also the code ?

Comment: Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/82/8213482/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2888

Answer (score 0):

Ive changed my string to this:

```
<?php
// Define what post types to search
function searchAll( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'category_name', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'partner','project', 'press', 'review' ));
    }

    return $query;
}

// The hook needed to search ALL content
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchAll' );
```

I do have custom taxonomies though.  Basically I'm trying to create a "Search everything" function.

Comment: This is the error code when using the above snippet:

Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/82/8213482/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2888